# How do I add a custom toolbar button to a Kendo UI grid within a tabstrip using Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm currently trying to build a Kendo UI grid within a tabstrip using Razor syntax. I'm running into a fairly niche problem that seems to be the result of 3 factors all playing against each other:

1. To render content within a tabstrip, I would normally do something like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
     .Items(items =>
     {
         items.Add().Text("Item").Content(@<text>CONTENT HERE</text>);
```

2. To create a custom button within a grid's toolbar, I would normally do something like this:

```
 .ToolBar(tools =>
 {
 tools.Template(@<text>BUTTON CODE HERE</text>);
```

3. As far as I can tell, Kendo UI doesn't support nesting `@<text>` tags

Given all three of those factors together, I haven't been able to come up with a method to successfully render a custom toolbar button within a tabstrip. Neither `tools.Custom` nor `tools.ClientTemplate` have worked for me (both failed to render the button without throwing an error, so I don't have a way to determine why they didn't work). What is the best way for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define the Grid in a partial view and [load it in the TabStrip](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/navigation/tabstrip/content). Also if you need a plain button you can use the Custom method to [add a custom command button](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/toolbar#custom-commands):

```
tools.Custom().Name("myButton").Text("Click me");
```

The button will get a `k-grid-mybutton` class that you can use as a selector to attach a click handler. [Here is a example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/wRFEOmkJ08UgqeRW43).